# How can an angular application lazy load an angular module from a different application?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I would like to lazy load an angular module into the host angular application from a different application. The host application's routes are defined as follows:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'admin', loadChildren: 'http://other.app.com/app/admin/admin.module#AdminModule' }
];
```

The module (component) is not loaded, and I get the following error:

```
core.umd.js:2844 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: (SystemJS) XHR error loading http://other.app.com/app/admin/admin.module
```

How could this be resolved, please?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add and set `defaultJSExtensions` to `true` in systemjs.config.js. The application/module is written in TypeScript.